# Add Current Date into first column for each row on array based second column

Tags: arrays, json, date, google-apps-script

Basically, this script copies the json data, if a value in a column exists, the value is replaced, but if not then the value is copied at the end of the row. it's just that I want to add the date in the first column, if there is, then the date will overwrite the previous date, if the data is not the same it will be copied in the next row, here's the script

```
function pasteDAta(dataReq) {
  const id = "1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // get header and the rest data from the sheet
  var [ headings, ...data ] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var values = dataReq.map((a) => {
    let holder = [];
    for (x in headings) {
      let output = headings[x] in a ? a[headings[x]] : "";
      holder.push(output);
    }
    return holder;
  });
  var len = values.length;

  var new_values = []; // values to add at the bottom of the sheet
  var col_b = data.map(x => x[1]);  // get column B from the data

  values.forEach(row => {
    // find an index of the row with the same value in cell B
    var row_index = col_b.indexOf(row[1]);

    // if nothing was found add the row to the new values
    if (row_index == -1) new_values.push(row); 

    // else change the found row on the sheet
    else sheet.getRange(row_index + 2, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]); // '+2' due the header
  }) 

  // add the new values at the bottom of the sheet
  if (new_values.length > 0)
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, len, new_values[0].length).setValues(new_values);

  return "Numbers of sheets added: " + len;
}
```

How do I add the current date into column A based column B according to script conditions ;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to add the current date to column A only when updating an existing row, or also when appending a new row? Also, what's the current value of `row[0]`, it's not a date? Also, about `it's just that I want to add the date in the first column, if there is, then the date will overwrite the previous date` does this mean if there's no date in column A (for example, if the cell is empty) you don't want to overwrite the cell? Or you want to add the current date no matter what?

Comment: First column  row[0] is empty, when rows updated, generate new date, row[1] is from json array

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a date to column A whenever a row is updated, you just have to use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor to get current date and assign `row[0]` to it:

```
else {
  row[0] = new Date();
  sheet.getRange(row_index + 2, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
```

If you wanted to add the date to appended rows, you'd add `row[0] = new Date();` before the corresponding `if...else` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot Iamblichus for this answer.